# Add new option button is not working in product custom option tab

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add a custom option for a product.

When I go to the `custom option` tab and click on `add new option` button, then nothing happens. I have also checked in the console but I couldn't find any errors there. Can anyone have any idea, how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is calling the catalog/productscontroller @optionsAction(). The add new option tab is controlled by a js script. The block creation is happening here:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options
```

Unless you have a class extending this one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue look like extension confliction. Have you installed the extension related the product?

You need to debug extension by disabling the extension one by one. Disable extension from xml file:

```
app/etc/modules/extensionfile.xml
```